# Netbeans is cutting short my jars manifest

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Netbeans is cutting off the Class-Path part of a manifest file that I am generating with maven.  It turns out like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: alan
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Main-Class: com.alan.client.Main
Class-Path: /home/alan/NetBeansProjects/RemoteInterfaces/target/Remote
 Interfaces-1.0.jar
```

It should be:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: alan
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Main-Class: com.alan.client.Main
Class-Path: /home/alan/NetBeansProjects/RemoteInterfaces/target/RemoteInterfaces-1.0.jar
```

I have bumped the margin value in the IDE to a bigger number and the red line has jumped to the right, but it's still not generating it correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: No line may be longer than 72 bytes (not characters), in its UTF8-encoded form. If a value would make the initial line longer than this, it should be continued on extra lines (each starting with a single SPACE).
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

Comment: Then I guess the above works, although my jar isn't being read by the app server.  Different issue though obviously, cheers.

Comment: Any exception message? Which app-server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Archiver putting in weird line breaks in classpath for manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402271/maven-archiver-putting-in-weird-line-breaks-in-classpath-for-manifest)

Comment: @Martin, I'm using Glassfish 4.1.  I have one class in the RemoteInterfaces.jar file, it's a remote interface for EJB.  I get this error in the server log when I deploy:

SEVERE:   Class [ Lcom/alan/SessionBeanRemote; ] not found. Error while loading [ class com.alan.client.Main ]

Comment: Well... I would wonder more, why your app references to a jar located in your IDE. Wouldn't it be better to pack it into your war/ear? And also, if you send your app to your operational team, would you tell them they should create /home/alan/NetbeansProject/.... on all the servers?

Comment: Hi Martin, just learning EJB at home at the moment, but I get you.  I'm trying to write a stand alone application that looks up the EJB in glassfish through JNDI.  I need the remote interface in the RemoteInterfaces.jar to do this.  Anyways, I got it working after a lot of experimentation with the classpath!  Thanks